# Vanila js and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, dom-events

how to make a button to disappear when rendering on the screen

```
function findRequireMessage() {
  const messages = document.querySelectorAll('.message');
  const requireMessage = Array.from(messages).find(message => message.className.includes('requestedReply'));
  if (requireMessage) { 
    requireMessage.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth' });
    return true;
  } else { 
    alert('No require message found.');
    return false;
  }
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  const findRequireButton = document.getElementById('find-require-button');
  findRequireButton.style.display = 'none'; // set the button to display none initially
  if (findRequireMessage()) {
    findRequireButton.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

I want this  display:"incline-block when first loading to check if there is a requireMessage in chat if it's true to  display the button else not to display anything in the chat

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: don't use `Array.from(NodeList)`. `querySelectorAll` retruns a Nodelist which is an array-like object and can iterate over the same as an array. Also, you can use `querySelectorAll('.message[class^="requestedReply"]')` to only select the elements you want in the first place.

Comment: we I add this querySelectorAll('.message[class^="requestedReply"]') not working

Comment: we I add this querySelectorAll('.message[class^="requestedReply"]') not working

Comment: Can you put your HTML, CSS and JS in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways you can do this, for example:

1. Adding `defer` to the HTML `<script>` tag

```html
<script src="path/to/js" defer></script>
```

2. Make the button invisible from the start

```html
<button id="find-require-button" style="display:none;"></button>
```

3. Wait a bit after DOMContentLoaded (this is not best practice, as the user might see the button disappearing)

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{}, 50 /* 50 milliseconds after DOMContentLoaded; this can be changed to any value */)
    // code
})
```

Comment: am getting an empty nodelist

Comment: NodeList []length: 0[[Prototype]]: NodeList
 requireMesage  undefined

Comment: @EliusGachango instead of using `message.className` in findRequireMessage, use `message.getAttribute("class")`